# How can I use spring on the following class?

Tags: java, spring

I am learning how to use sprint and to be honest I think it's useful when you know what to inject. I am having a dilemma on the following class:

```
package Edamam;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class EdamamApi {
   private String ApplicationIDRecipes;
   private String ApplicationKeyRecipes;
   private String ApplicationIDIngredients;
   private String ApplicationKeyIngredients;

   public EdamamApi(){
       Properties prop = new Properties();
       InputStream input = null;
       try{
           input = new FileInputStream("src/main/java/Edamam/Edamam.properties");
           prop.load(input);
           this.ApplicationIDRecipes = prop.getProperty("Application_ID_Recipes");
           this.ApplicationKeyRecipes = prop.getProperty("Application_Keys_Recipes");
           this.ApplicationIDIngredients = prop.getProperty("Application_ID_Ingredients");
           this.ApplicationKeyIngredients = prop.getProperty("Application_Keys_Ingredients");
       }
       catch(IOException ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }finally{
           if(input != null){
               try{
                   input.close();
               }
               catch(IOException e){
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }
   }

   private String makeUrlForRecipes(ArrayList<String> ingredients){
       boolean isFirst = true;
       String url = "https://api.edamam.com/search?q=";
       for(String ingredient : ingredients){
           if(!isFirst)
               url = url + "%20";
           isFirst = false;
           url = url + ingredient;
       }
       url = url + "&app_id=" + this.ApplicationIDRecipes + "&app_key=" + this.ApplicationKeyRecipes;
       return url;
   }

   private String makeUrlForIngredients(String ingredient){
       String url = "https://api.edamam.com/api/nutrition-data?app_id="+this.ApplicationIDIngredients+
                    "&app_key="+this.ApplicationKeyIngredients+"&ingr=1%20large%20"+ingredient;
       return url;
   }

   private ArrayList<String> toArrayList(JSONArray arr){
       ArrayList<String> StringList = new ArrayList<String>();
       for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
           StringList.add(arr.getString(i));
       return StringList;
   }

   public ArrayList<RecipePojo> getRecipes(ArrayList<String> ingredients){
       String url = makeUrlForRecipes(ingredients);
       ArrayList<RecipePojo> recipes = new ArrayList<RecipePojo>();
       try {
        JSONObject response = JsonReader.readJsonFromUrl(url);
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("hits");
        int NumberOfRecipes = 20;
        int jsonIndex = 0;
        while(jsonIndex < jsonArray.length() && NumberOfRecipes > 0){
            JSONObject objectInArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(jsonIndex);
            String recipe = objectInArray.getJSONObject("recipe").getString("label");
            String ImgURL = objectInArray.getJSONObject("recipe").getString("image");
            ArrayList<String> IngredientLines = toArrayList(objectInArray.getJSONObject("recipe").
                                                 getJSONArray("ingredientLines"));
            RecipePojo newRecipe = new RecipePojo(recipe, ImgURL, IngredientLines);
            recipes.add(newRecipe);
            jsonIndex++;
            NumberOfRecipes--;
        }
       } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      return recipes;
   }

   public NutritionFactsIngredient getNutritionFacts(String ingredient){
       String url = makeUrlForIngredients(ingredient);
       System.out.println("the url is: " + url);
       NutritionFactsIngredient facts = null;
       try{
          JSONObject response = JsonReader.readJsonFromUrl(url);
          int Calories = response.getInt("calories");
          int TotalWeight = response.getInt("totalWeight");
          JSONArray DietLabelsJson = response.getJSONArray("dietLabels");
          JSONArray HealthLabelsJson = response.getJSONArray("healthLabels");
          JSONArray CautionsJson = response.getJSONArray("cautions");
          ArrayList<String> DietLabels = this.toArrayList(DietLabelsJson);
          ArrayList<String> HealthLabels = this.toArrayList(HealthLabelsJson);
          ArrayList<String> Cautions = this.toArrayList(CautionsJson);
          facts = new NutritionFactsIngredient(Calories,TotalWeight,
                                               DietLabels,HealthLabels,Cautions, ingredient);
       }catch (JSONException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }catch (IOException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return facts;
   }
}
```

I don't know if we should let spring handle the life-cycle of every object in our application. I just added the @component annotation on my class to get a taste of Spring, but I think that it's not enough. I am still instantiating objects with the new keyword inside of my methods. Should I make the classes RecipePojo and NutritionFactsIngredients components?. This is so confusing because the instances of these classes are not unique. They depend on user input. How can I use Spring on this class?

Edit: So people are telling me that instead of doing this:

```
@Component
public class EdamamApi{
  public EdmamApi(){}
  public Recipe getRecipe(String recipe ){
     Recipe rep = Recipe(recipe);
     return rep;
  }
}
```

I should do this

```
@Component
public class EdamamApi{
  public EdmamApi(){}
  public void makeRecipe(String recipe,  Recipe rep){
     rep.setRecipeName(recipe);
  }
}
```

In that way, the class is not tied down to Recipe and I can just use a bean Recipe.

--->THIS IS NOT RIGHT BUT IT'S WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACCOMPLISH <------

```
@Component
public class EdamamApi{
  public EdmamApi(){}
  public Recipe getRecipe(String name){
      @Autowired 
         Recipe rep;
       rep.setName(name);
      return rep;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow.  There's so much that could and probably should change about this code.  First thing in the DI world:   Don't read the property file in your constructor. That ties the class to the file system. Just pass in all those strings in the constructor and let spring read the property file.

Comment: May be this link is useful :) [Spring component and autowired](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire)

Comment: @RobertMoskal I am going to reduce the size of my question.

Comment: Why are you *wanting* to use Spring?

Comment: Learning a new technology.

Comment: Could we get some more info on your setup? Are you using Spring Boot? Are you using maven? If so, how about a copy of your pom.xml? As a rule of thumb a POJO should not be a component since it's default scope is singleton so the users would be rewriting each others input. You could make the pojo's request scoped but if they are holding user input it's no sin to manually instantiate them using the new keyword.